# Trying to insert one ajax call inside an html email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I'm trying to make an email poll where my users should rate the service they had.

Something simple (see image below)

[image: survey poll]

I know how to do it using the syncronous way:

```
  <form action= "myAction" method="post"> ... <input>....
```

Anyway, each time I try to do something with javascript, gmail removes it:
Example:

```
          <script> mymethod(){..}
          </script>
         <button onclick="mymethod">
```

turns inspecting the mail into just:

```
         <button >
```

Any reason?

Comment: You are most likely not going to be able to run JavaScript in an email. Most strip all JavaScript from the HTML before displaying for security reasons.

Comment: Can only create this on a web page, not in an email

Answer (score -2):

try

```
button onclick="mymethod()"
```

or

```
input onclick="mymethod()"
```

also mymethod must have word "function".

Like this:

```
function mymethod(){
  //
}
```